# Can't boot into Windows after installing Ubuntu with WUBI

Tags: boot, wubi

I installed Ubuntu with the Windows installer and when I turn on my computer, Ubuntu just starts and I can't get to Windows again. Windows is my main OS for developing apps so I need to be able to access it.

Please help.

Answer (score 2):

That's weird I thought Windows MBR appeared before GRUB when you used the WUBI install. Anyway you could try holding the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to see if GRUB shows and then select Windows.

Also once in Ubuntu you could change the `GRUB_TIMEOUT=X` line on this file `/etc/default/grub`. To do that type the following in a terminal:

```
gksu gedit /etc/default/grub

sudo update-grub
```

Note that the X represents the value in seconds.

Hope this helps.

Comment: To the asker: In a nutshell, hold SHIFT as a temporary aid. To Este, please don;t forget that you need to run `sudo update-grub` afterwards.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try not to forget again. My first post forgive me lol.

Comment: No problem. Everyone has a first post :-). Even the mods.